# Set Azure Static Web App Custom Domain as Default

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-static-web-app

I have Azure Static Web Apps with one or more custom domains. I create the static web app and the [custom domains via azure powershell.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/new-azstaticwebappcustomdomain?view=azps-7.4.0)

In the Azure Portal I can set the default domain like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/custom-domain-default).

My problem is, I don't know how I can achieve this via Azure Powershell and couldn't find any help for that. How can I set a custom domain as default using Azure Powershell?

Comment: AFAIK, we can not configure it PowerShell it seems , You may raise [**feature request**](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/a222eda7-2425-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f09d0)  . only We can set the hostname with [az-cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/staticwebapp/hostname?view=azure-cli-latest#az-staticwebapp-hostname-set-examples)